# PTIJ: Oldest Game in the World

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

What is the oldest game in the world? Is it hide and seek, when Adam hid from Hashem in Gan Eden?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: It's actually cricket, as it says in Genesis 1:1, "In the big inning."

Answer (score 11):

Older than that is a game called "Simon says." In it, something happens, only because "Simon says" it should happen. When Hashem made the world, he did it through [saying](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.1.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) so. In fact, the original name was "shim'u, na, omer" -- listen up please, I'm saying something.

Answer (score 1):

The oldest game in the world is Chess, as the medrash says

http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/toshba/kohelet/3a-2.htm#1

> (קהלת ג יא): "אֶת הַכֹּל עָשָׂה יָפֶה בְעִתּוֹ גַּם אֶת הָעֹלָם נָתַן
> בְּלִבָּם מִבְּלִי אֲשֶׁר לֹא יִמְצָא הָאָדָם אֶת הַמַּעֲשֶׂה אֲשֶׁר
> עָשָׂה הָאֱלֹהִים מֵרֹאשׁ וְעַד סוֹף"( פירוט ): "מכאן, שהיה הקב"ה בונה
> עולמות ומחריבן, בורא עולמות ומחריבן, עד שברא את אלו"
>
> Hashem created worlds and destroyed them, till He created this world

Why did Hashem create worlds and destroy them?

It is clear that Hashem was playing nuclear chess in which the winner gets to nuke his opponent.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it was Peek-A-Boo, when G-d created light and darkness on the first day of creation.

Comment: Who was hiding from who?

Comment: How is creating light and dark peek-a-boo?

Comment: usually when you 'play' peek-a-boo with a baby you cover your face with s/t and then pop your head out and say "peek-a-boo!". This in essence is what transpired on the first day of creation. G-d created light and darkness which had appeared from nothing

Answer (score 0):

The first game is Minecraft because G-d created the world in steps, "morning," "evening," in six days, like minecraft block-stepping.